# DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) will get date-time for exactly 24hrs ago, but how do I get the time for yesterday at a specific hour?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I want to somehow specify a time in my `Datetime.Now` so for instance I know that

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

will get the date for yesterday exactly 24hrs ago but I want to get the date for yesterday at a specific time, for instance 5pm.

I can't find anything useful in relation to this on StackOverflow, any suggestions?

Comment: The date will remain the same for yesterday what every time you pass to AddDays, if you want time then you can use the time you already know like 5pm

Comment: 1)You can create a timespan to subtract from now until THE TIME you want and then add it as minutes/hours or whatever you prefer...;

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(17);
```

Comment: This (or the answer by Nikhil) should have been accepted. I prefer the single liner myself but both are valid answers.

Comment: @dubbreak 15 upvotes for an obviously wrong answer? This gets the time 7 hours ago.

Answer (score 10):

You can create an instance of `TimeSpan` and delete/add in `DateTime.Now`.

OR

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

DateTime newdt = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 17, 0, 0);
```

Comment: 5pm but other than that spot on

Answer (score 0):

```cs
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1);
DateTime startOfYesterday = new DateTime(yesterday.Year, yesterday.Month, yesterday.Day, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endOfYesterday = startOfYesterday.AddDays(1);
```

using this it will be work